# How can I pass a mouse click event within javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, svg

I am trying to implement drag and drop for javascript.I need to pass the event but it is returning undefined.
I have already tried passing window.event directly.Does not work

```
var lens = svg.append("circle")
.attr("id","lens")
.attr("class","draggable")
.attr("cx",40)
.attr("cy",40)
.attr("r",40)
.style("fill","grey");

//Setting click handler
lens.on("click",function(e){
selectElement(e)});

 function selectElement(e) {       
     console.log(window.event); //This prints UNDEFINED
     console.log(e);  //This prints UNDEFINED

    var evt = e || window.event;    
     console.log(evt);  //This prints UNDEFINED
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried with html5 drag and drop? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Answer (score 1):

SVG uses evt to monitor an event.
Try the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SVG evt</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg width=400 height=400>
<circle id=myCircle cx=200 cy=200 r=100 fill=blue stroke=none onClick=showEvt(evt) />
</svg>
<script>
function showEvt(evt)
{
    var target=evt.target
    console.log(target.getAttribute("id"))

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Have you checked out jQuery UI? https://jqueryui.com/ This might help
>   you. Here is a basic set up for dragging and dropping:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

> Regarding your click event try this:

```
$('#id').click(function(){
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a Javascript Mouse Event tutorial that will allow you to tie into mouse events without using jQuery or other library:

[JavaScript Mouse Events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events)

with a working fiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/iamthejonsmith/q0sc4mae/

and example code:

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="btn">
<input type="button" value="right-click me" id="btn2">



document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  alert('click!')
}

document.getElementById('btn2').oncontextmenu = function() {
  alert('right click!')
}
```

Comment: That seems to be HTML rather than SVG.

Comment: Title of question:

"How can I pass a mouse click event within javascript?",

therefore, I presented a javascript solution. The html buttons were for convenience, the methods are javascript

Comment: It's tagged svg, not html and the code in the question is d3 code to generate SVG. event handling in SVG is (rather sadly), subtly different.

Comment: 1. I completely overlooked the SVG tag.
2. I was unaware of the difference in event handling with SVG, so thanks for the info!